# Add and Delete dynamic textbox row in angular 2

Tags: angular

I tried the below my code

```
<div class="form-group" *ngFor="let fieldValue of fieldValues; let last='last';">
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="fieldValue.name" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <input type="text" name="value" [(ngModel)]="fieldValue.value" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" (click)="addFieldValue(fieldValue)" *ngIf="last">Add</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default"  type="button" *ngIf="!last" (click)="deleteFieldValue()">Delete</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

ts file

```
export class AppComponent {
    private fieldValues: Array<any> = [];
    constructor() {
        this.fieldValues = [{
            name: null,
            value: null
        }]
    }

    addFieldValue(field) {
        this.fieldValues.push(field);
    }

    deleteFieldValue() {

    }
}
```

My Problem is that i have to add fields when dynamically whenever the add button is clicked new field should be generated which is empty also retain the first field in the array.

[image]

Thank you advance

Comment: [check this](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/reactive) detailed explanation of reactive and dynamic reactive forms

Comment: this is case for using reactive forms so i pasted that link. ngModel wont help here

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve? It's a bit unclear to me, if you want empty fields why push `fieldValue` to your array? This also makes all the objects the same instance.